# Copying Files without Data and Just Names and Extensions

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

Is there a way to copy files so that to show a client our file structure and what files we have available but the files are essentially just shells of the actual files? Meaning that they just contain the name and extension but not any of the actual data.

Comment: How about the CMD `tree /f` ? That shows the directory structure graphically.

Comment: That could be a possibility, but it would be nice to allow it to be searchable in file explorer. Also do you know of anyway to export the output to a text file format that preserves the graphics? When I do tree /f > test.txt the graphics are not visible.

Comment: so you want to copy a directory and have all the files be blank in the copy?

Comment: To view the output as tree structure, open in Notepad and select font `Terminal`. That replaces the superscript 3 etc. with horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: Or use ```tree /f /a``` to draw the tree with standard ASCII characters rather than line-drawing characters.

Comment: Or just `dir /s /b`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -Recurse |
 Foreach-Object {
  $_.fullname
  $FullPathAndNameWithoutDrive = Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -NoQualifier
# For directories, create a directory.  
  If ($_.PSIsContainer) {
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\Temp2$FullPathAndNameWithoutDrive
  }
# For files, create an empty file.   
  If (!$_.PSIsContainer) {
    echo $null > C:\Temp2$FullPathAndNameWithoutDrive
  }

 }
```

That will loop through everything in C:\Temp. It'll then create a matching version in C:\Temp2, with the same directories, and with empty (just containing a Null character) files. Change C:\Temp and C:\Temp2 to fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

[Snap2HTML](https://www.rlvision.com/snap2html/about.php) seems like something you might be interested it. it generates a pretty nice navigable & searchable html page based on your directory structure.